# How to generate Rust docs for type aliases?

Tags: rust, documentation

In a library I have a compressor that supports two "modes" with different APIs, but the same data model some common logic. Here's how I've written it DRY:

```
struct BaseCompressor<M: Mode> {...}
impl<M: Mode> BaseCompressor<M> {
  /// some docs...
  pub fn header(...) -> ... {...}
}

pub type CompressorA = BaseCompressor<ModeA>;
impl CompressorA {
  /// some docs...
  pub fn chunk(...) -> ... {...}
}

pub type CompressorB = BaseCompressor<ModeB>
impl CompressorB {
  /// some docs...
  pub fn data_page(...) -> ... {...}
}
```

I'm quite happy with structuring the logic this way so that `CompressorA` and `CompressorB` share data members and logic for `header`. However, it screws up the generated docs, rendering absolutely nothing meaningful for `CompressorA` and `CompressorB`. I would rather not expose `BaseCompressor` in the public API. Is there any way I can get full docs for `CompressorA` and `CompressorB`? Or perhaps a better way I can structure this?

Comment: I'm not sure this is how Rust is intended to work, as you're steering quite heavily towards some kind of object-inheritance pattern here.

Comment: @tadman A struct generic over some behavior is perfectly idiomatic Rust, and in fact the foundation of patterns like typestate. The choice of prefix "base" might make it sound OOP-y, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Trying your example locally (slightly adjusted), I get this result from `cargo doc --open`:[image: Rust generated documentation for BaseCompressor]

Would this satisfy your needs? I do have another way to structure your code which I would prefer:

Since you said the APIs for the modes are different, you could just have 2 separate structs that both contain a `BaseCompressor`:

```rust
// Private base type
struct BaseCompressor;

impl BaseCompressor {
    // Some shared logic
    pub fn header() {} 
}

// Mode A
pub struct CompressorA {
    inner: BaseCompressor
}

impl CompressorA {
    // API for mode A
    pub fn chunk() {}
}

// Mode B
pub struct CompressorB {
    inner: BaseCompressor
}

impl CompressorB {
    // API for mode B
    pub fn data_page() {}
}
```

Comment: I would rather not expose `BaseCompressor` in the public API - I don't want people relying on it. And unfortunately in your other solution, I would need to duplicated the signature for `header` and documentation in both `CompressorA` and `CompressorB`.